# Video do youtube para uma videoview

Tags: android, android-studio

Necessito de passar um video através do link para dentro da minha app android , eu tentei este código :

```
String video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/76JpysFZ2VM";
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(video);


        vid1.setVideoURI(uri);
        vid1.start();
```

Código completo :

```
package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Index extends AppCompatActivity {


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    // JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    int a;


    // products JSONArray

    public TextView descricao1;
    public TextView descricao2;
    public TextView descricao3;
    public TextView descricao4;
    public TextView descricao5;
    public TextView descricao6;
    public TextView videodescricao1;
    public TextView videodescricao2;
    public TextView videodescricao3;
    public TextView videodescricao4;
    public TextView videodescricao5;
    public TextView videodescricao6;
    public TextView videodescricao7;

    public ImageView img1, img2, img4 , img3, img5 , img6;
    public VideoView vid1;
    ListView lista;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.single_post);
        descricao1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao);
        descricao2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao2);
        descricao3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao3);
        descricao4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao4);
        descricao5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao5);
        descricao6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricao6);
        videodescricao1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo1);
        videodescricao2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo2);
        videodescricao3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo3);
        videodescricao4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo4);
        videodescricao5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo5);
        videodescricao6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo6);
        videodescricao7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdescricaovideo7);
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
         VideoView vid1=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
        img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
        img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img4);
        img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img5);
        img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img6);
        String descricao = getIntent().getExtras().getString("descricao");
        String imagens = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imagens");

        String[] img = imagens.split(";");



        String video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/76JpysFZ2VM";
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(video);

        System.out.println("URI"+uri);
        vid1.setVideoURI(uri);
        vid1.start();


        int i;
        String[] s = descricao.split("Imagem [0-5]+");
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
            if (img.length >= 1) {

                    descricao1.setText(s[i]);


                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[0]);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        input.close();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        in.close();
                        img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }


                }
            }  if (i == 1) {
            descricao2.setText(s[i]);
            if (img.length >= 2) {



                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[1]);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {

                        InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        input.close();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        in.close();
                        img2.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }


                }


            }
            if (i == 2) {
                descricao3.setText(s[i]);
            if (img.length >= 3) {


                    {


                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[2]);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {

                            InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                            input.close();
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                            in.close();
                            img3.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }if (i == 3) {
                descricao4.setText(s[i]);
                if (img.length >= 4) {



                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[3]);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {

                            InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                            input.close();
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                            in.close();
                            img4.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }
                    }
                }
            if (i == 4)

            {
            descricao5.setText(s[i]);
            if (img.length >= 5) {



                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[4]);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {

                        InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        input.close();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        in.close();
                        img5.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }
                }
            }if (i == 5)

            {
            descricao6.setText(s[i]);
            if (img.length >= 6) {



                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + img[5]);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {

                        InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        input.close();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        in.close();
                        img6.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }
                }


            }


        }


    }
}
```

Não obtive sucesso. Alguém me poderia ajudar?

Preciso de um código não muito grande e facil de se entender!

Comment: Retorna algum erro ou não acontece nada ?

Comment: O video nem aparece nao acontece nada

Comment: Pela pesquisa que fiz já não é mais possível visualizar vídeos do *youtube* dessa forma. Veja este [aqui](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/android-development-play-youtube-video-in-your-app-cant-play-this-video-and-troubleshooting/) uma forma alternativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem após varias tentativas achei duas maneiras de resolver o problema uma das maneiras é utilizar o Youtube Android Player api , que existe instalação de bibliotecas e tudo mais mas é o na minha opinião o recomendado.

Eu não utilizei pois envolvia algumas linhas de código então descobri que dá para fazer através de uma WebView fica aqui o exemplo :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?autoplay=1&vq=small");
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: Gostei da ideia de utilizar o "embed" +1

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma classe específica, **que funciona**, para esse tipo de aplicação. Veja como ela funciona, nos comentários e adapte ao seu código. Perceba que não são somente 3 linhas que fazem um vídeo rodar corretamente:

```
public class MeuVideoViewActivity extends Activity {
    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mController;
    private Uri uriYouTube;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //VideoView
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mController);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        /*
        CASO O VIDEO ESTEJA NO SEU DISPOSITIVO

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.sample);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();*/

        //Aproveitando o recarregamento anterior
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("Loc");
            Log.i("Localização: ", loc + "");
            uriYouTube = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
            videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
            videoView.seekTo(loc);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.v("Preparação", "ok");
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        } else {

            //Setando o link e iniciando o AsyncTask
            RTSPUrlTask truitonTask = new RTSPUrlTask();
            truitonTask.execute("http://www.youtube.com/embed/76JpysFZ2VM");
        }

    }

    //Função que starta o vídeo(SIMPLES COMO VOCÊ FEZ)

    void startPlaying(String url) {
        uriYouTube = Uri.parse(url);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("Loc", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
        outState.putString("url", uriYouTube.toString());
    }

    //Menus opcionais

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Iniciando AsyncTask para rodar o vídeo em segundo plano

    private class RTSPUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = getRTSPVideoUrl(urls[0]);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            startPlaying(result);
        }

        public String getRTSPVideoUrl(String urlYoutube) {
            try {

                //API NECESSÁRIA
                String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        .newDocumentBuilder();
                String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
                URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
                Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                String cursor = urlYoutube;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = list.item(i);
                    if (node != null) {
                        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                        HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                            Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                            maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                        }
                        if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                            String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                            if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                                cursor = maps.get("url");
                            if (f.equals("1"))
                                return cursor;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cursor;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return urlYoutube;
            }
        }

        public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            String id = null;
            for (String row : param) {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
            return id;
        }
    }

}
```

Coloque permissão de acesso total a rede (Internet) e leitura do dispositivo de armazenamento externo no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[Fonte](http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/)

Comment: Continua sem funcionar

Comment: Vou te mostrar uma classe específica pra fazer isso.

Comment: obrigado fico a espera

Comment: PRONTO!.........

Comment: Acredito que o código funcione mas eu não consigo entender o código e é demasiado grande , eu vou precisar de varios videos